# How to convert a Groovy map to key="value" string?

Tags: groovy

I need to take map and convert it to a string with the key/value pairs separated into key="value".
I can do the following, and this works, but is there a "groovier" way to make this happen?

```
void "test map to string"() {
given: "a map"
Map fields = [class: 'blue', type:'sphere', size: 'large' ]

when:
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
fields.each() { attr ->
    stringBuilder.append(attr.key)
    stringBuilder.append("=")
    stringBuilder.append('"')
    stringBuilder.append(attr.value)
    stringBuilder.append('" ')
}

then: 'key/value pairs separated into key="value"'
'class="blue" type="sphere" size="large" ' == stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

Comment: in case this is html (or xml), remember, that you might have to quote or even encode the values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can `map.collect` using the desired format:

```
Map fields = [class: 'blue', type:'sphere', size: 'large' ]

toKeyValue = {
    it.collect { /$it.key="$it.value"/ } join " "
}

assert toKeyValue(fields) == 'class="blue" type="sphere" size="large"'
```

Comment: Good solution if you don't need nested maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use groovy's `map.toMapString()` method.

```
Map fields = [class: 'blue', type:'sphere', size: 'large' ]
fields.toMapString()
```

Comment: this does not convert to the desired format.

Comment: Yeah, this would be great if it worked, but I still get a map looking like this: `[version: 1.2.3-4]` and it doesn't eval correctly. Unexpected token due to the punctuation in the value.